# Is there a way to determine the Physical Sector Size for removable drives with file systems other than NTFS (like FAT16, exFAT...)?

Tags: delphi, filesystems, disk

I need a function to get the Physical Sector Size for all kind of system drives, in Win7 or higher.

This is the code that I've used until today, when I found out that it's not working with my external USB HDD (exFAT file system) and with my USB MP3 Player (FAT16). In these cases the function `DeviceIoControl` fails and I get the exception: "System Error. Code 50. The request is not suported". But it works very well with NTFS volumes.

```
function GetSectorSize(Drive:Char):DWORD;
var h:THandle;
    junk:DWORD;
    Query:STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY;
    Alignment:STORAGE_ACCESS_ALIGNMENT_DESCRIPTOR;
begin
 result:=0;
 h:=CreateFileW(PWideChar('\\.\'+UpperCase(Drive)+':'),0,FILE_SHARE_READ or FILE_SHARE_WRITE,nil,OPEN_EXISTING,0,0);
 if h=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then RaiseLastOSError;
 try
  FillChar(Query,SizeOf(Query),0);
  Query.PropertyId:=StorageAccessAlignmentProperty;
  Query.QueryType:=PropertyStandardQuery;
  if not DeviceIoControl(h,IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY,@Query,SizeOf(Query),@Alignment,SizeOf(Alignment),junk,nil) then RaiseLastOSError;
  result:=Alignment.BytesPerPhysicalSector;
 finally
  CloseHandle(h);
 end;
end;
```

Comment: Are these other drives advanced format drives? What does `fsutil` tell you about these drives.

Comment: The MP3 Player with FAT16 I think it can't be advanced format (it's just a USB stick), and `fsutil fsinfo ntfsinfo` doesn't work for the other USB HDD because it is exFAT, but I think it can be advanced format because it has 1TB.

Answer (score 2):

According to MSDN:

[File Buffering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc644950.aspx)

> Most current Windows APIs, such as IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_GEOMETRY and GetDiskFreeSpace, will return the logical sector size, but **the physical sector size can be retrieved through the [IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff800830.aspx) control code, with the relevant information contained in the BytesPerPhysicalSector member in the [STORAGE_ACCESS_ALIGNMENT_DESCRIPTOR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff800831.aspx) structure. For an example, see the sample code at [STORAGE_ACCESS_ALIGNMENT_DESCRIPTOR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff800831.aspx).** Microsoft strongly recommends that developers align unbuffered I/O to the physical sector size as reported by the IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY control code to help ensure their applications are prepared for this sector size transition.

This same quote also appears in the following MSDN document:

[Advanced format (4K) disk compatibility update](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh848035.aspx)

Which includes the following additional information:

> The below list summarizes the new features delivered as part of Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012 to help improve customer and developer experience with large sector disks. More detailed description for each item follow.
>   ...
>   •Provides a new API to query for physical sector size (FileFsSectorSizeInformation)
>   ...
>
> Here’s how you can query for the physical sector size: 
>   **Preferred method for Windows 8**
>
> With Windows 8, Microsoft has introduced a new API that enables developers to easily integrate 4K support within their apps. This new API supports even greater numbers of scenarios than the legacy method for Windows Vista and Windows 7 discussed below. This API enables these calling scenarios:
>
> •Calling from an unprivileged app
>   •Calling to any valid file handle
>   •Calling to a file handle on a remote volume over SMB2
>   •Simplified programming model
>
> The API is in the form of a new info class, FileFsSectorSizeInformation, with associated structure FILE_FS_SECTOR_SIZE_INFORMATION

[FILE_FS_SECTOR_SIZE_INFORMATION structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh406395.aspx)

> This information can be queried in either of the following ways:
>
> •Call [FltQueryVolumeInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff543443.aspx) or [ZwQueryVolumeInformationFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567070.aspx), passing **FileFsSectorSizeInformation** as the value of *FileInformationClass* and passing a caller-allocated, **FILE_FS_SECTOR_SIZE_INFORMATION**-structured buffer as the value of *FileInformation*.
>
> •Create an IRP with major function code [IRP_MJ_QUERY_VOLUME_INFORMATION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549318.aspx).
>
> •Call [FsRtlGetSectorSizeInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh920377.aspx) with a pointer to a **FILE_FS_SECTOR_SIZE_INFORMATION**-structured buffer. The **FileSystemEffectivePhysicalBytesPerSectorForAtomicity** member will not have a value initialized by the file system when this structure is returned from **FsRtlGetSectorSizeInformation**. A file system driver will typically call this function and then set its own value for **FileSystemEffectivePhysicalBytesPerSectorForAtomicity**.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx  <-- As this states, these are bytes per logical sector: "Most current Windows APIs, such as IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_GEOMETRY and GetDiskFreeSpace, will return the logical sector size..."

Comment: @marusnebunu: You should have expanded on that comment, as the rest of that same sentence explains how to get the physical sector size.

Comment: Yes, I've done that (see the function from my question), and it works fine with NTFS file systems but not with exFAT or FAT16.

Comment: Unfortunately `FILE_FS_SECTOR_SIZE_INFORMATION` structure is available starting with Windows 8.

Comment: Right. You can use `IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY` in Vista and Win7.  Physical sector size is not exposed in earlier versions, you have to use `IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_GEOMETRY` or equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Your principal error is that you try to get physical sector size from a volume handle rather than from that of an underlying physical device (`\\.\PhysicalDriveX`). Device's physical sector size doesn't depend on FS and shouldn't be confused with a logical sector size defined by FS properties.

Comment: I'm not convinced by that. The MSDN example code suggests that specifying mapped drive name is fine: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff800831.aspx

Comment: No, it's not working even with `\\.\PhysicalDriveX`. I've tested.